# jackson - root element read Tree vs pojo

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-rest

Hi I want to parse a json that i retrieve by hitting an legacy system,  and build a response json. We are using Spring Boot having a jackson dependency. The problem i have is almost 75% of fields from legacy can be mapped directly or on basis of simple rules (0: false, 1:true). But, there are some complex rules as well like based on certain conditions and data present in some fields, we can map them to a nested object etc. To cater to this requirement which approach should we consider -

1. POJO approach to fetch the data from legacy target. Use bean util. copyproperties to populate the response bean (75% of properties), and then apply the business transformations on this POJO to tranform based on business logic. (Would we need two pojos here a. to copy from beanutil.copyproperties and then b. create final response dto ??)
2. Do not use pojo directly parse the JSON apply the transformations and then create a new POJO or response DTO. (But, this may not be generic solution and would need to be done on case by case basis).

Main considerations are approach should be fast, and generic to be applied like a framework. Thanks aakash

Comment: Transforming a type-safe, documented Java object (mapped to your legacy API messages) to another object looks much more easier, cleaner and more maintainable to me than transforming a JsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

The considerations should be like below:
- Are the POJOs reusable?
- Is the JSON multilevel and very large?

If the answer is yes for both, then better to choose POJOs for cleaner implementation. Otherwise JsonObject parsing.
Hope this will help.